# Powershell Alias exists and doesn't exist at the same time

Tags: powershell

I have a function and an alias to call that function defined on my powershell profile `.ps1` file.

`New-Alias -Name 'updateDolibarrDBPruebas' -Value 'UpdateDolibarrDBPruebas' -Scope Global`

if I call the alias I get this message

```
updateDolibarrDBPruebas: The term 'updateDolibarrDBPruebas' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I tried copypasting the function on my current powershell session then executing the previous `New-Alias` command but I get this error:

```
New-Alias: The alias is not allowed, because an alias with the name 'updateDolibarrDBPruebas' already exists.
```

`Get-Alias` shows

```
Alias           updateDolibarrDBPruebas -> UpdateDolibarrDBPruebas
```

I've tried closing all powershell windows and opening a new one so the profile gets loaded again but I still get the same errors.

Comment: Why did you create the alias in the first place? PowerShell's command discovery API doesn't care about casing, so `updateDolibarrDBPruebas` would have already worked if `UpdateDolibarrDBPruebas` exists and is discoverable

Comment: It was that, I thought it had worked before because I had `updateDolibarr16` as alias for `UpdateDolibarrDB16` and it worked, I didn't notice that I deleted the **DB** from the alias, so I was overwriting the function with the alias I guess?